# Wordpress menu - how to add colour to active category

Tags: css, wordpress, themes

I'm making a theme for WordPress. My primary menu in the header consists of both pages and categories. Using the "current-menu-item" class I am able to make the background of the menu item for the active page a different colour, but it doesn't work for the categories. I tried stuff like "current-cat-item" thinking it would be an easy thing and I've google what I can but I can only find "fixes" that take 20+ lines of code and I feel like there must be an easier way - like with the pages.

Comment: Can you please share your website url. So i can give you the easiest solution.

Comment: I'm working on a localhost server, I don't have a website I was asked to build a theme for someone else's website which is not currently running wordpress. But as I said, there is a function to select the current menu item but it doesn't work for the categories in the menu item, only the pages.

However, that was asked a few days ago and I've now found a way to make pages containing individual categories which is a better solution for this assignment. I'm still interested in figuring out how to do it but it's no longer "urgent".